# Positional Encoding of 2D grid

Tags: encoding, transformer-model

I have a 100 x 100 grid where certain (x,y) coordinates have a 32 dimension feature vector. I want to find the 2D positional encoding for this grid and add that to the feature vector at that position. So, for each x,y coordinate:

new feature = original feature + PE(x,y)

but  I am confused about the implementation from: https://github.com/tatp22/multidim-positional-encoding.

The input has to be of the form `(batch size, x, y, ch)` where `ch = 32` and `x, y` are the coordinates. But, the calculated PE is also of size `(batch size, x, y, ch)`. How  do I extract the PE for certain positions in this case?

Thanks a lot